# How can I make a proper JPA repository for Posts and Comments using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jpa

I am making a simple board application that the users can write a post and replies.
In my opinion, I can use embedding(nested array) for replies(reply means comment, not answer) into the each post.
so the entity class will looks like:

```
data class Place(
    val id:String,
    val content: String,
    val author: String,
    val title: String,
    val replies: List<Reply>
)
```

and my JPA repository is implements a MongoRepository interface.
It provides default CRUD methods for Place entity, but not the replies.

How can I make a CRUD repository for a Reply?